# Is OK to post a challenge for a sandbox post with 0 votes but is 1 week old

Tags: support, sandbox

Is OK to post a challenge for a sandbox post with 0 votes but is 1 week old?

I have a lot of sandbox posts  with 0 votes that are posted to Main, But this is OK?

Answer (score 9):

#### Post Sandbox challenges when they're ready to be posted, not based on score or time

The reason score/time are recommended (e.g. wait a week, have a positive score etc.) is because these are usually good ways of measuring if your challenge idea will do well. For example, a negatively scored Sandbox post is unlikely to do well posted on main, and a challenge left in the Sandbox for an hour won't get the feedback it might need.

But, these are *recommended*, not hard limits. People who are experienced challenge writers will often skip the Sandbox, or leave an idea for only a couple of days to get feedback, often in the form "Will this be a good idea?", because they're experienced enough to iron out any kinks in the spec by themselves.

Ultimately, you should post a challenge from the Sandbox once it is ready to be posted. If you aren't entirely sure if a challenge is ready, ask people in chat - often a "Any last feedback on [this challenge](https://example.com)?" message will get a response or two saying if it looks good to post, or if it needs more feedback.